# Toggling divs in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to toggle divs by clicking on links. but things are not going well for me when I click on a link it shows a new div but don hide the previous one

JavaScript Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle(id){ 
        var el = document.getElementById(id);
        if(el != null && el.style["display"]== 'none'){ 
            el.style["display"] = "block";
        }
    }
</script>
```

My divs code

```
<?php foreach($titles_data as $title){ ?>
 <div style="display:none" id="content_<?php echo $title['idtitles'] ?>">
   <div id="left-ad"></div>
 </div>
<?php } ?>
```

My links code

```
<?php foreach($titles_data as $title){ ?>
<li class="flag_<?php echo strtoupper($title['language']) ?>">
 <a id="title_<?php echo $title['idtitles'] ?>" href="" title="<?php echo $title['title'] ?>" onclick="toggle('content_<?php echo $title['idtitles'] ?>')">
 </a>
</li>
<?php } ?>
```

How can it be done so that when i click on link its respective iv becomes visible and the previous one hides?

Thanks

Comment: With the current code, you are not hiding the previosly toggled div element!

Comment: Consider using a JavaScript framework like JQuery. It will greatly help you with your work and make your life easier.

Comment: Why did you select the `jquery` tag if you're not using it?

Answer (score 1):

Using native JS:

```
function toggle(id){
    var el = document.getElementById(id);         
    el.style.display = el.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
}

toggle("myId");
```

Using jQuery:

```
function toggle(selector) {
    $(selector).toggle();
}

toggle("#myId");
```

Answer (score 0):

To toggle the display, you dont need to do that much

```
$("#elementid").toggle();
```

In reference to your question

```
$('a').click(function() { // however this is select all anchors, better use class
                          // selector like $(".mylinkclass")
   var id= $(this).attr('id'); //get the id
   var ids = id.splite("_"); //split the id on "_", to extract the idtitles
   $("#content_"+ids[0]).toggle(); // use that to toggle
});
```

Comment: @FaryalKhan, I am not sure, what `content_{some id}` display. Do you have a link where i can check, the full html, to see the layout structure

Comment: I dont have the link but u can just consider it as a single div

Comment: @FaryalKhan, I updated the answer with explanation every bit, rest is up to you

Comment: Thanks for your quick response n help

Comment: @Starx I don't think he is asking about hiding/showing divs. On the last line of his question he says : "How can it be done to keep the id of active div ?"

Comment: @PratikChandra, I dont know, OP should be clear on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is always only one div that is displayed, you can check for it:
Alter your logic, to declare a global variable to hold the value of the currently visible div. And then update that variable whenever a link is clicked, to hold the id of the currently visible div. So, using your exisitng code, you can do this :

**using core javascript**:

```
var visibleDiv;
function toggle(id){
   // hide the previous div using visibleDiv
   if(document.getElementById(visibleDiv)!= null) document.getElementById(visibleDiv).style["display"] = "none";
   var el = document.getElementById(id);
   if ( el.style["display"] == "" || el.style["display"] == 'none' ){
        el.style["display"] = 'block';
    }
   visibleDiv = id; // update the current visible div name
}
```

**using jquery** like this :

```
var visibleDiv;
$("[id^=content_]").each(function() {
if($(this).is(':visible')){
   visibleDiv = $(this).attr('id');
}

});
```

Comment: what I actually want to do is that I have an already active div with id = 'main-content' and other divs are hidden with ids = content_{id} where id is number... and there are different links per one hidden div I want to replace the hidden div by an active div when I click its respective link

Comment: You should have the previously active div id in the variable, *visibleDiv*. In your second comment, if you mean that, you want to replace the currently visible div with the clicked-link's div, then you can use the visibleDiv variable to hide the previous one. 
Also, if it's not working, try inspecting with firebug and then let me know what is the error???

Comment: whwn i click for the 2nd time the visDiv is again main-content div. I edited the question kindly have a look at it so that you better understand what I m trying to do

Comment: you say : "if i click on the 2nd link **it** needs to replace the content_2 div with **the one** that is clicked". what is "IT" and "THE ONE" here? You are clicking on a link, right? So, what needs to be put inside the **"content_2"** div?

Comment: just tell me how to replace a div with id = content_11 with another div of id = content_12

Comment: when i click on a link it makes its corresponding div visisble but it dont hide the the previous div how can I hide the previous div and show the current one at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Check my new answer. I just created the sample html page, with 3 divs. Initially all are shown. When you click on one of them, it is hidden. When you click on some other div. The old one is made visible again and the current one is hidden. Modify the logic as per your requirements.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>asdsa</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var visibleDiv;
function toggled(id){   
    //$('#div_2').html($('#div_1').html());
    if(document.getElementById(visibleDiv) != null){ document.getElementById(visibleDiv).style["display"] = "block";}
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    document.getElementById(id).style["display"] = "none";
    visibleDiv = id;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div_1" onclick="toggled('div_1')">div1</div>
    <div id="div_2" onclick="toggled('div_2')">div2</div>
    <div id="div_3" onclick="toggled('div_3')">div3</div>   
    <hr/>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but either this is not what i require or its not working for me :(